# Как правильно паковать в exe проект JavaFX + Spring Boot? Проект на Gradle

Tags: java, javafx, spring-boot, spring-data

Друзья, помогите человеку, который не разбирается в системах сборки. Для удобства воспроизвидения проблемы закинул файлы на [GitHub](https://github.com/Addm1X/Issues/issues/1). Я запускаю с Spring Boot приложение на JavaFX с использованием FXWeaver. Далее я планирую использование JDBC Template для работы с БД. В примере из репозитория эта функция работ, а вот при попытке собрать проект с jpackage в exe вылезают проблемы с пакетами. Я вроде все указал в `module-info.java`, но всё равно вылезает ошибка, я понятия не имею по какой причине:

```
error: package reactor.blockhound.integration does not exist
provides reactor.blockhound.integration.BlockHoundIntegration with org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry.SpringCoreBlockHoundIntegration;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подключить в проект maven/gradle и использовать плагин launch4j.

Comment: в проекте уже используется `gradle`. С ошибка Log4j я разобрался, осталась только `package reactor.blockhound.integration does not exist` Что такое Reactor Blockhaund я понятия не имею

Comment: @Tsyklop окей, я попробовал собрать с помощью `launch4j` и всё вышло. Почему так же просто нельзя через `jpachage`?

Comment: @AddminX Не знаю. Я не пользовался `jpachage`. Нужно изучать ошибку, гуглить ее. Может есть баг репорт у них. В общем - искать.